# How to add extra query URL variable when editing a post in Wordpress gutenberg block editor?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

Since Wordpress 5 and Gutenberg block editor, every update to post is now Ajax based making it difficult to add a redirect or add GET variable to the URL.

For eg:

```
/wp-admin/post.php?post=1161&action=edit
```

I would like to add

```
/wp-admin/post.php?post=1161&action=edit&additional=value
```

But as soon as I press the update/publish button, it reverts back to its original url form:

```
/wp-admin/post.php?post=1161&action=edit
```

How do I make it so any additional get variable is retain after publishing or updating a post?

Comment: What is the purpose of this, what are you trying to achieve with this additional value?

Comment: @CBroe additional query var is just an example, if I wanted to add "&foo=value" , how would I add it to the url? I can use JS and use pushstate, but once I press publish/update button. The url reverts back to post.php?post=1234&action=edit.

Comment: You would probably have to manipulate URLs contained inside the page as well - like the `action` of the form that gets submitted when a post is updated.

Comment: @CBroe I actually tried it, but since its an ajax call the action for save_post hook are triggered in JS not in php. I had to resort to JS setInterval to force it to always have it.. its ugly and dirty but works...